# application of a static variable Python

Tags: python-3.x, static, blackjack

I've tried googling and checking online repositories for what I assume is a very basic noob question.

The overall function: BlackJack 21 game(Python), 1 human player, 1 bot dealer
The execution: 1 class called Player(), Player 1 = Player('Tim'), Player 2 = Player('bot')
The issue: static variable within the class

class Player():

```
wallet = 100
hand = []
hand_value = 0

def __init__(self,name):
    
    self.name = name        
    
def raise_value(self):
    print(f' Your current balance is {wallet}')
    while True:
        amount = int(input("Please select your raise amount :"))
        if amount > wallet :
            print(f' Im sorry but that bet is {amount - wallet} over your available funds')
        else:
            return amount
            break
def hit_stand(self):
    hit_stand = input("do you want to hit or stand (H or S)").lower()
    if hit_stand == 'h':
        return True
    elif hit_stand == 's':
        return False
```

The questions I have is the use of a class variable allowing it to have a unique value, meaning that when I create Player1 = Player('Tim'), the wallet value will remain 100, regardless of whether I create dealer = Player('bot') and assign its wallet value to 200.

I dont know whether to place the wallet variable above the `__init__(self)`: or within it. Either way I try doing it, the `def raise_value(self)` cannot pick it up and returns a `NameError: wallet not defined`

Answer (score 0):

You are having multiple problems which are compounding:

1. static variables are the same *for the whole class*
2. static variables are accessed as classname.variable

If you want the wallet to be different for each player, it should be a *member variable*, also called an *attribute*

Those should be defined inside any method (including **init**), but must be prefixed by self. when creating and accessing:

```
def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.wallet = 100
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. When studying the concepts with basic examples, it seems so easy. But the minute I have to put it into application, i seem to get overwhelmed

Comment: I always feel the same way learning a new language!